# Laravel Condition based sql query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models which are joined. I need to get `workspace_members` table details only when `inventory.status` is 1(i.e active).
How can I write that condition in larvel eloquent. Below is my query. Thanks in advance.

```
$data['inventories'] = Inventory::
    Join('category_info','inventory.category_id','=','category_info.category_id')
    ->leftJoin('workspace_member_inventory', 'inventory.inventory_id', '=', 'workspace_member_inventory.inventory_id')
    ->leftJoin('workspace_members','workspace_member_inventory.member_id','=','workspace_members.member_id')
    ->where('inventory.workspace_id', '=', $workspace_id)
    ->select('inventory.*', 'workspace_member_inventory.member_id','workspace_members.*','category_info.category_name', 'inventory.status as status')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood but I think that you are looking for [Laravel Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes)

Write the scope on your Inventory model:

```
public function scopeIsActive($query,$status = null){
   if(!is_null($status)){
       if($status == 1){
          return $query->leftJoin('workspace_members','workspace_member_inventory.member_id','=','workspace_members.member_id')->where('inventory.status',1);
       }else{
        return $query->where('inventory.status',0);
       }
   }else{
      return $query;
   }
}
```

Then add it to your query:

```
$data['inventories'] = Inventory::
    Join('category_info','inventory.category_id','=','category_info.category_id')
    ->leftJoin('workspace_member_inventory', 'inventory.inventory_id', '=', 'workspace_member_inventory.inventory_id')
    ->where('inventory.workspace_id', '=', $workspace_id)
    ->isActive(1)
    ->select('inventory.*', 'workspace_member_inventory.member_id','workspace_members.*','category_info.category_name', 'inventory.status as status')
    ->get()->toArray();
```